# Htaccess external server rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have subdomain xxx.example.com. I'm in folder 'images'. So my url is xxx.example.com/images/
I want to make a rule that redirect 'xxx.example.com/images/test/' to address 'yyy.com/test.php'.
My code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /images
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteRule ^test$ http://yyy.com/test.php [P]
```

But i have error 404. What's wrong?

Comment: First of all, did you enable `mod_proxy` ? You have to do it if you want to use `P` flag. Also, if your url has a trailing slash (`images/test/` and not `images/test`) your rule should be: `RewriteRule ^test/$ http://yyy.com/test.php [P]`. And finally, seeing your code, your htaccess has to be in your `images` folder. Is it the case ?

Comment: Or make trailing slash optional `^test/?$`

Comment: @JustinIurman I wrote to the administrator and learned that this service is disabled. Is there any other option to do something like this?

Comment: If you want your browser's url to be `xxx.example.com/images/test/` while having the content from `yyy.com/test.php`, you don't have a choice except using `mod_proxy` with `P` flag like you did, especially if the other domain is not on the same server as the first one.